Can I check if a TextInput is secured with detox?
Is it possible to check if my text input is secured (value is hidden for a password field)?
We can toggle the secured attribute with a "show password" button.
Can we check that toggle is working using Detox ?
I would need a "isSecured()" method :
await expect(element(by.id('textInputTestID'))).<method>

I did not find anything in the getAttributes() documentation. Tried to read '.value' or '.text' :  secured or not those values won't change.
